# How to update git in centOS 6

Tags: centos, git, vagrant

I have installed chef workstation on centOS 6 using vagrant. My current git version here is 1.7.1

In the `git config --list`, it is not accepting `push.default = simple`. 
How can I update this git version to the latest one through terminal.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using 6 years old OS? You may use RPMForce repository:  http://akyl.net/how-install-latest-version-git-centos-6x

Comment: rpmforge and repoforge are dead in the water. Take a look at my answer...

Comment: @nwildner oops, you are right. Then building from sources (your approach) is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Updated GIT version to 2.4.4 on Centos 6.6 Vagrant VM ["minimal/centos6"](https://app.vagrantup.com/minimal/boxes/centos6)

```
yum install curl-devel expat-devel libcurl-devel perl-devel asciidoc xmlto xz zlib-devel gettext

curl -kOL https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.4.4.tar.xz

tar xvf git-2.4.4.tar.xz

cd git-2.4.4

make configure

./configure --prefix=/usr

make all

sudo make install install-doc install-html
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/448814/yum-doesnt-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos6/604124#604124

Answer (score 1):

You could enable [repoforge](http://repoforge.org/) repository and install a newer version of it. But, as you can see, this repository is dead:

> RepoForge might be outdated. We have no updates since very long time.

Best option is to compile from source. Install the dependencies:

```
# yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel gcc perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
```

Remove your git software installed through package manager:

```
# yum remove git
```

Download the version you want from here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/

```
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-<version>.tar.gz
# tar xzf git-<version>.gz
# cd git-<version> 
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
```

Comment: Hi, for the wget command, I am getting error 404.

Comment: @Yash open ``https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/`` with browser to see list of files

Comment: This is because you need to ACCESS the site, select one version(say 1.8.5 for example - https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.8.5.tar.gz) and download THE version you want. Some people may not need the "bleeding-edge" version of `git`

Comment: Yes, I installed the 2.8.4 version and it worked. One more question. Do I need to execute all these commands from src folder?

Comment: No. You can download it and unpack inside your home. This is just to make  things in a more organized way. Keep in mind that if you need to remove git is just a matter of accessing this git source folder and type `make uninstall` so, better keep the house clean :)

Comment: I already did in the src folder. How can I change it to home folder?

Comment: `mv /usr/src/your_git_folder /home/your_user/folder_you_want`. That is basic moving stuff around Unix...

Comment: I am root now. So the home folder for root is /. Do you want me to move these files to root home or user home?

Comment: You can move it wherever you want...

Comment: Thanks for your time. One final question. is it necessary that I need to install git as root. Or can I install it as user?

Comment: Install it as root, but operate `git` command as normal user. For security reasons a normal user will not be able to write inside `/usr/local` and thus, install software from source on this directory :)